# Run-time error '424' - Object required

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm working on a VBA - Word form and I'm trying to make it where when the user selected a checkbox, they enter in a value corresponding to the checkbox. I don't have a lot of experience with VBA since I usually never work with this kind of thing. So when I run the program I get the error code I posted as the title.

```
'When checked, number of days must be > 0.
If chkOnLine.Value = True Then
    If txtOnLine.Text <> "" Then
        blnTemp = IsNumeric(txtOnLine.Text)
        If Not blnTemp Then
            blnError = True
            strError = "On-line sessions must be numeric."
            GoTo EndError
        End If
        If txtOnLine.Text <= 0 Then
            blnError = True
            strError = "Value must be greater than zero."
            GoTo EndError
        End If
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Which line of code is triggering the error?

Comment: Your code lacks context. My hunch is that either `chkOnLine` or `txtOnLine` aren't properly set (they seem to be the only place in the fragment that requires an object) but those variables are declared and (hopefully) given values outside of the code that you show.